# How to properly include javax.json jar to a deployed .jar file

Tags: java, jar, jdeveloper, manifest.mf

I'm trying to include `javax.json.jar` to my project in **Jdeveloper 12c IDE**

The **final** `phillplugin.jar` includes:

- `META-INF` folder containing `MANIFEST.MF` file
- `phillplugin` folder which includes my `phillplugin.class`
- `javax.json-1.0.2.jar` file
- `phillplugin.xml`

Although the server **crashes** because it doesn't recognize my javax.json class from the `MANIFEST.MF` file with the following Error:

```
Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.json)
```

This is how i'm exporting it:

1. **Right click** the project -> **properties**
2. **Libraries** / **Classpath** -> checking the `javax.json-1.0.2.jar`
3. **Deployment** -> editing deployed my profile
4. **File Groups** -> new -> **type**: Libraries **name**: lib
5. **Contributors** : Everything is checked
6. **Filters**: checking the `javax.json-1.0.2.jar`

and then im deploying it.

Is the way i'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to include in my `MANIFEST.MF` like so: `org.json;resolution:= optional,org.json.JSONObject;resolution:=optional`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: PhillPlugin
Bundle-Version: 10
Bundle-Name: PhillPlugin
Bundle-Activator: phillplugin.PhillPlugin
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",oracle.security.am.
 plugin,oracle.security.am.plugin.authn,oracle.security.am.plugin.impl
 ,oracle.security.am.plugin.api,oracle.security.am.common.utilities.pr
 incipal,oracle.security.idm,javax.security.auth,org.json;resolution:=
 optional,org.json.JSONObject;resolution:=optional
```

as well as the `.jar` and the `library`

[image]